# drop out vs dropout vs drop-out

Tags: grammar, british-english

If I understand correctly, I have to use one of these 3 forms depending on the case:

verb: **drop out**

noun: **dropout**

modifer: **drop-out**

Are the following 7 examples spelled correctly in British English?

1) Predicting student **dropout** in higher education

2) Student **drop-out** prediction

3) A student who **dropped out**

4) We consider these students as **dropouts**

5) Most **drop-out** students

6) 50% of the **dropout**s

7) Create **drop-out** prediction models

Comment: It needs to be noted that "dropout" (in several of the above presentations) is often used in a technical sense, everywhere from electronics to bicycles.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary has **[drop out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop-out)** as a "phrasal verb", and **[dropout](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dropout)** as a noun.  It does not have an entry for **drop-out** - but you could check other dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries generally agree that *drop out* is the verb form and *dropout* or *drop-out* is the noun form. (See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop%20out), which has *dropout* for the noun, and the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/57894?rskey=eyvb8I&result=2#eid), which has *drop-out* for the noun.) This fits a [general pattern](https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/2017/09/20/we-just-got-the-go-ahead-nouns-formed-from-phrasal-verbs/) for nouns formed from phrasal verbs: as a noun they tend to form a word without a space or a hyphenated word:

> go-ahead, breakdown, mix-up

The same ambiguity persists for the adjective. Collins Dictionary lists *[dropout](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dropout)* as an adjective and noun form, noting "also drop-out." So both forms are used for nouns and adjectives.

If you go by frequency, *dropout* is about ten times more frequent in the Corpus of Contemporary American English than *drop-out* (around 2600 compared to around 250). The [Ngram search](http://%3Ciframe%20name=%22ngram_chart%22%20src=%22https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=dropout%2C%20drop-out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdropout%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrop%20-%20out%3B%2Cc0%22%20width=900%20height=500%20marginwidth=0%20marginheight=0%20hspace=0%20vspace=0%20frameborder=0%20scrolling=no%3E%3C/iframe%3E) is flawed with hyphenation but generates a similar result.

One final factor is that [compound adjectives that express a single idea are often hyphenated](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp). So if you wanted to conform to this rule, the adjective form would be *drop-out*.

So it's your decision how you use the noun and adjective forms. You can technically use *dropout* for both, use *drop-out* to distinguish the adjective from the noun, or even go against common usage and use *drop-out* for both. You make the call.